# Android populating spinners from mysql JSON data

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

i have 2 spinners one for Province and other for City. But they dependent to each other.if i select Gauteng in Province spinner the second spinner must show Johannesburg,Pretoria,Centurion and if i select KZN in province i want the second spinner to show Petermaritsburg,Durban,Ulundi.

Here is my code. i can populate spinner from my mysql db but i cant create dependencies the other

first spinners JSON data:

```
   "Provinces": [
    {
        "provinceid": "1",
        "provincename": "A"
    },
    {
        "provinceid": "2",
        "provincename": "B"
    }
]}
```

second spinners JSON data: (İt related on provinces in my php and db.

//getting values for listing cities
 $provinceid= $_POST['provinceid'];)

```
{
"Cities": [
    {
        "cityid": "1",
        "cityname": "AA"
    },
    {
        "cityid": "2",
        "cityname": "BB"
    }
]}
```

Here is my java code.

```
private ArrayList<String> province;
private ArrayList<String> city;
private JSONArray provinces;

String ilceid;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

                ilce = new ArrayList<String>();

                //Initializing Spinner
                spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
                spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);


                //Adding an Item Selected Listener to our Spinner
                //As we have implemented the class Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener to this class iteself we are passing this to setOnItemSelectedListener
                spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(WelcomeActivity.this);
                spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(WelcomeActivity.this);
                getData();

}


private void getData(){
    //Creating a string request
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(SharedPrefManager.DATA_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    JSONObject j = null;
                    try {
                        //Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
                        j = new JSONObject(response);

                        //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
                        provinces= j.getJSONArray(SharedPrefManager.JSON_ARRAY);


                        getProvinces(provinces);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    //Creating a request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
private void getProvinces(JSONArray j){
    //Traversing through all the items in the json array
    for(int i=0;i<j.length();i++){
        try {
            //Getting json object
            JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);


            province.add(json.getString(SharedPrefManager.TAG_PROVINCENAME));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Setting adapter to show the items in the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(WelcomeActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, province));
}
private String getProvinceId(int position){
    String provid="";
    try {
        JSONObject json = provinces.getJSONObject(position);
        course = json.getString(SharedPrefManager.TAG_PROVINCEID);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return provid;
}


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
}}
```

First spinner works in this case. But how do i populate spinner2 depending on first spinner ?

Answer (score 0):

You don’t even need to get that data from database, they are the same for all users and they can not be changed so you can put that datas in app. But if you really need that than you will make that seperate, when user choose first option than you need to post that to db and then get options for that option. I think there is no another way if I understand you what you really need.

Comment: yes you're right. But my app will work in changeable provinces and cities. But i need to be able to update provinces and cities from database. So i cant change datas in app @elvirt

Comment: I’m not sure if there is than option another than post first value to db and based on that get value for second one. But that is too slow. What if you put all data in sqlite db on device and than once daily check if are changes in online database and if are than update sqlite db?

Comment: Actually i do. in my php,api posts first value to db and get value based on that. My problem is in java and spinner methods. How can i do in java ? populating first spinner thats ok. And than post data to my db and getting second json array for spinner2 and populate